# Unwanted line wrapping behavior in the Text view of SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, text, uikit, uuid, monospace

guys！

I found that (in SwiftUI) if a String contains the '-' character, and the '-' character is immediately followed by a non numeric character, then the string will break at the position of the '-' character（If there is not enough space）

As can be seen from the following figure, the String with blue background has a line break, while the String with gray background does not. Because the '-' character at the line break of the former is followed by a non numeric character (A), while the '-' character of the latter is followed by a numeric character (8)

[image]

Although the text fonts that display them are of equal width, their actual display widths are still different (the blue background String is shorter due to line breaking)

(If the '-' character in these Strings is replaced with other characters, line breaking will not occur.)

The test code is as follows：

```
let g_uuidString_1 = "474E34DD-3A83-456D-8182-8E298550BC93"
let g_uuidString_2 = "B2367045-EA26-455B-9D47-EB22D3593C5C"

struct ContentView: View {
    let uuidString_1 = UUID().uuidString
    let uuidString_2 = UUID().uuidString
    @State var width_1 = 0.0
    @State var width_2 = 0.0
    @State var fontSize = 15.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                //Text(uuidString_1)
                Text(g_uuidString_1)
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
                    .overlay(
                        GeometryReader { geo in
                            Color.clear.onAppear {
                                width_1 = geo.size.width
                            }
                        }.id(fontSize)
                    )
                    
                
                //Text(uuidString_2)
                Text(g_uuidString_2)
                    .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.5))
                    .overlay(
                        GeometryReader { geo in
                            Color.clear.onAppear {
                                width_2 = geo.size.width
                            }
                        }.id(fontSize)
                    )
                    
                    
            }
            .padding()
            // Use a constant width font（monospaced） to ensure that Strings 
            // with the same number of characters have the same display width
            .font(.system(size: fontSize, design: .monospaced))
            
            Spacer()
            
            Text("widths: \(width_1) | \(width_2)")
                .padding(.bottom)
                .font(.title2)
            
            Slider(value: $fontSize, in: 5.0...50.0)
                .padding(.top, 200)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

**How can we ensure that (in UIKit or SwiftUI) the display width of the String generated by any UUID above is the same？ Thanks! ;)**

Comment: while the linked duplicate is plausible, if you're going to modify the string anyway, a better way would be to replace the hyphens with U+2011 (NON-BREAKING HYPHEN).

Comment: As to why it behaves this way (treating numeric characters differently than non-numeric), that's because it's required by Unicode rules. See http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/#LD11. The rule for the Hyphen class (HYPHEN-MINUS) is "Provide a line break opportunity after the character, except in numeric context."